# Problems after Razor update in VS2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, razor

After installing some updates in VS Package Manager (including Razor update), my Intellisense and code Highlighting is malfunctioning. Even the basic things like model, ViewBag, Html.BeginForm() are all being highlighted red; hovering over them shows either 'doesnt exist in current context' or 'so and so doesnt have definition for BeginForm'...Ironically the code compiles perfectly as before and runs fine...

What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor 3 uses a new engine, which VS2012 doesn't have. You can add support by installing the new [ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx)